# MVC Call and pass view to layout in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am developing an MVC project which has a layout file with a panel in which all the contents will be displayed. The layout resembles the following sketch:
[image]

For the sake of explanation, let us assume that on the content frame I will display multiple blog posts belonging to a same category (which was selected on the side nav). Each of these blog posts have a specified layout such as the following, and will be rendered as a partial view by calling a controller action. [image]

So, if the user selects to view the Cooking posts on the side nav, this will trigger the Cooking Action on the BlogController. The Cooking Action renders the Cooking view which will then call on the BlogController again and ask for the CookingFirstPost, CookingSecondPost actions. These will render posts as partial views succesfully.

HOWEVER. This is an overkill when the selected category has only one blog post. This will make an unnecesary double trip to the controller. What I wish is to manually use the blog post layout inside the content section when only one blog post is expected, so that I do not need to call my controller again to render the partial view.

Please notice that in my example the blog posts are fixed and it will always be like this, I am not going to have DB access.
Greetings
Luis.

Comment: Why are you worried about double calls to the controller?  In the context of a single HTTP round trip, I don't think any reasonable number of calls to the controller would be noticable

Comment: I don't understand your question.  I don't see any reason for CookingFirstPost and CookingSecondPost actions to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you going back to your controller each time you want to load a blog item? Why aren't you just loading them in one round trip when the "Cooking" action is executed?

If you have 10 cooking blog posts, you should be loading all 10 into your cooking view in one hit I would have thought.

I can't really work out what you need to happen well enough from your description.

Comment: The best option is to paginate the Content and display X posts for each page (Example: 10/1000). This is the best option if he have a lot of posts (100+)